# MySQL - Query with IN-clause performing badly

Tags: mysql, performance, entity-attribute-value

I have a MySQL-database with four tables (item,property,snapshot and value). Basically the table *value* contains the value of a certain *property* of an *item* given a certain date (*snapshot*).

[image]

The table *value* contains the following columns

- value_id
- FK_itemid (foreign key for item)
- FK_propertyid (foreign key for property)
- FK_snapshotid (foreign key for snapshot)
- value (as string)

Now I would like to get the value of a certain property(-id) for all items for which other properties have specific values:

```
SELECT * FROM
            (SELECT * FROM remian.remian_propertyvalue WHERE 
                                            FK_ItemId IN (SELECT FK_ItemId FROM (SELECT * FROM remian.remian_propertyvalue WHERE FK_PropertyId=1) AS trackerentries WHERE trackerentries.Value IN (12,11) AND
                                            FK_ItemId IN (SELECT FK_ItemId FROM (SELECT * FROM remian.remian_propertyvalue WHERE FK_PropertyId=12) AS statustable WHERE statustable.Value NOT IN ("Rejected","Closed")) AND
                                            FK_ItemId IN (SELECT FK_ItemId FROM (SELECT * FROM remian.remian_propertyvalue WHERE FK_PropertyId=2) AS projectentries WHERE projectentries.Value IN (73,74)))) AS queried
WHERE queried.FK_PropertyId=12 AND FK_SnapshotId = 1;
```

This query does work but is very slow (80 seconds for 5000 entries). Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Questions about query performance should include `SHOW CREATE TABLE [table]` for every table involved and `EXPLAIN [query]` outputs.

Comment: I'm tagging your question [tag:entity-attribute-value] because you're implementing something very similar to that pattern. Basically you're inventing a new database with its own meta-schema implemented as key/value pairs in MySQL. This is sometimes called the [Inner-Platform Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect). You might be happier with a document database like MongoDB.

Comment: Why use a relational database and then ignore all of its design principles? This is a sincere question, not snark.

Answer (score 0):

EAV schemas are terribly messy to work with. Using `IN ( SELECT ... )` just makes it worse *and slower*.

You need to try to do it with no subqueries, just `JOINs`, something like

```
SELECT *
    FROM remian_propertyvalue AS a
    JOIN remian_propertyvalue AS b  USING(FK_ItemId)
    JOIN remian_propertyvalue AS c  USING(FK_ItemId)
    WHERE a.FK_PropertyId = 1  AND a.value IN (12,11)
      AND b.FK_PropertyId = 12 AND b.value IN ("Rejected","Closed")
      AND c.FK_PropertyId = 2  AND c.value IN (73,74)
      AND a.FK_PropertyId = 12 AND a.FK_SnapshotId = 1;
```

Furthermore, do not have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` on the "property" table.  Instead have

```
PRIMARY KEY(itemId, propertyId),
INDEX(propertyId, value)
```

There could be issues with these indexes; I really need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to help.

More:

- Key-value schema: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta
- EAV: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav